How to horizontally center a genealogy tree using the genealogytree package in LaTeX?
I'm using the genealogytree package in LaTeX to create a family tree, but I'm having trouble horizontally centering the tree within the document. No matter what I try, the tree seems to align to the right. I've experimented with different commands and options, but haven't been successful in achieving the desired result.
Here's an example of the LaTeX code I'm using to generate the genealogy tree:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\gtrset{
    node size=3cm,
    level size=3cm,
    level distance=8mm,
    place text={\newline}{},
    box={
        fit basedim=9pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
        halign=flush left,before upper=\parskip1pt,\gtrDBsex
    }
}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,transform shape]

    \genealogytree[id suffix=@a]{
       sandclock{
          child{
            g{a} p{b} c{c} c{d} c{f}
            child{
                g{g} p{h} c{i} c{j} c{k}
                child{
                    g{l} p{m} c{n} c{o} c{p}
                }
                child{
                    g{q} p{r} c{s} c{t} c{u}
                }
            }
          }
       }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Here's a visual representation of what is happening:


Welcome! Can you edit your example so we can reproduce the problem?

I tried replacing the missing tree specification with the sandclock example from the documentation I found and that looks pretty much centred to me, so I assume the cause for the shift is in the code you've not shared. Note that it is not generally good to scale diagrams due to the effect on fonts and rules. However, it doesn't shift them anyplace.

@cfr the tree is pretty big for pasting it here (more than 900 lines), but nothing different from the ones in the documentation, I've been just copy pasting from there

Then reproduce the issue with a tree from the docs and post the code here. I tried to do that. The tree looked fine. You have to provide the means to reproduce the problem or nobody can help but you.

@cfr I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I edited the post with a more clear example and a real representation of how is the tree exported.

Well, your genealogy tree is wider than \textwidth (the width of the text area, or the width of the page minus the margins), which is why ultimately the \centering doesn't work (or rather, worked in a way you didn't want).

I am not quite sure what exactly the expected result should be (as your graph is very wide). Perhaps you want to shift the position of some of the nodes? The documentation of the package gives some instructions on how to manually shift the positions. In your example, manually shifting the nodes i and n to the left would solve the overall width issue.

Note that LaTeX tells you it is too wide on the terminal and in the log. Overfull \hbox (139.55838pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1061--1062. Many editors also inform you of this. (At least, Kile certainly does.) So you have to make the tree skinnier or the text area broader. Or, if you really wish, you can lie to LaTeX. That's not usually a great idea, but sometimes it does the trick.

That tree is too wide, so it doesn't fit. I think your question is really more about how to make genealogy trees narrower. One way is to shift things sideways. In this case, if you change the q node to be
g[pivot=child]{q} you will get this instead:

Here this 'pivot' node gets the middle place under the parents. Besides "pivot" you can also check "pivot shift" in the documentation. This is still much too wide, but at least now it's all visible. If you add the showframe option to geometry you can clearly see how much too wide it is.
The question about how to center a figure that is too wide (using the margins) has answers for examples here.
